# Taking away Selenium screenshot function makes program fail - Python

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get('https://soundcloud.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
#driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
signIn_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='g-opacity-transition frontHero__loginButton g-button-transparent-inverted sc-button sc-button-medium loginButton']")
signIn_button.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
#driver.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
#emailField = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form#loginForm input[placeholder="Your email address or profile URL *"]')Your email address or profile URL *
emailField = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='textfield__input sc-input sc-input-large'][@type='text']")
emailField.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
emailField.send_keys(account.email)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
emailField.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

When line `driver.save_screenshot('screenie.png')` is in the code, the program functions normally and correctly enters in the `emailField` with the correct string. When this code is removed however, the program fails trying to manipulate this text field and throws error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be
>   manipulated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a timing issue. `save_screenshot` is an expensive command so its delaying the script enough time for the elements in the login popup to become visible.

Setting implicit wait before any command won't do anything, `implicit wait` is being set one time for the `driver`. This tell the `driver` to look for the *existence* up to the specified amount of time for the driver life span.

To make sure the element is visible use `explicit wait` with `expected conditions`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get('https://soundcloud.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

signIn_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='g-opacity-transition frontHero__loginButton g-button-transparent-inverted sc-button sc-button-medium loginButton']")))
signIn_button.click()

emailField = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='textfield__input sc-input sc-input-large'][@type='text']")))
emailField.click()
emailField.send_keys(account.email)
emailField.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```